# How to create 3 column fluid layout with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't seem to find the answer to my question and I am having difficulties with bootstrap.

I am trying to make a 3 Column layout for a web page. I want each sidebar to take up 3 columns and fill that space and have the center content area take up 6 and fill the space. I found an example online and tweaked it a bit, but couldn't get the results I want.

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 span-3" >
        <div class="sidebar-nav-fixed affix" id="Left-Side">
            <div class="well">
                <ul class="nav ">
                    <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.well -->
        </div>
        <!--/sidebar-nav-fixed -->
    </div>
    <!--/span-->
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 span-6" id="Content">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

            <p>
                This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It
                includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces
                of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more »</a>
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!--/span-->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 span-3" id="Right-Side">
        <div class="sidebar-nav-fixed pull-right affix">
            <div class="well">
                <ul class="nav ">
                    <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.well -->
        </div>
        <!--/sidebar-nav-fixed -->
    </div>
    <!--/span-->
</div>
<!--/row-->
```

This is as far as I have gotten. I am very new to using bootstrap and don't really understand how to properly use it. Just in case this matter I am doing this project with ASP.NET.

[image: This is what the page looks like when loaded.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct and the layout is rendering as it should. Your problem is the **"affix"** class on your sidebars is causing them to collapse to the width of the content. Do you need these sidebars in a fixed position? If not then remove the **"affix"** class. Otherwise you will have to give these containers a width in order to fill the 3 column spacing.

Try something like this...

```
.sidebar-nav-fixed {
width: 25%;
padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked good. I also removed the pull-right on the Right sidebar and it looks just as I wanted it.